# OnTextChanged forcing me to click button twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I'm working on an asp.net, c# web app. I have a textbox (with validators) defined as...

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="VehicleAmt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
   OnTextChanged="VehicleAmt_OnTextChanged" 
   causesvalidation="true"
   Width="35px"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Font-Size="12px"
          ControlToValidate="VehicleAmt" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="#CC3300"
          SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="[0-99999]*" Display="Dynamic">
  </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidatorVehicleAmt"
         ControlToValidate="VehicleAmt"
         Display="Dynamic"
         ErrorMessage="Required"
         runat="server"/>
```

Elsewhere on the form I have a telerik RadGrid with the last column being a button. This is defined as...

```
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ActionColumn">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton Text="" runat="server" ID="lnkAddVehicle" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="AddVehicle">
   <img src="images/buttons/add.png"/>
  </asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

The VehicleAmt_OnTextChanged method does some db saving. The problem is when I type something in the textbox then click on the add button, I actually have to click on the button TWICE in order for the button code to run. Any ideas why this is happening and how I can enable single click for this?

I did notice that I have a standard asp.net button, and a single click does seem to work for that.

FYI: The code for AddVehicle, in part is this...

```
    protected void RadGridAvailableItems_ItemCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName != "Sort" && e.CommandName != "Page" && e.CommandName != "ChangePageSize")
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        int VehicleId = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["VehicleId"].Text);

    switch (e.CommandName)
        {

            case "AddVehicle":
                :
                break;              
        }
    }
    rebindGrids();

    panErrorMessages.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: maybe post code for "AddVehicle".  Validation for the from will be two-part... one part client-side and one-part server-side, so be careful that you keep those intact.  It's not clear whether AddVehicle uses the form data or not.

Comment: @pcalkins I added some of the code for the button so you can see. But, it doesn't even enter the method until I click twice.

Comment: ok, you could have a malformed linkButton tag there.  I don't think it's designed to be used like that... (shouldn't have a closing tag).  You probably just want a standard link if the image is going to be the button.

Comment: @pcalkins I don't think that's the problem. I've used it like that alot of times. But thanks for the idea! :)

Answer (score 0):

With `AutoPostback` set to `"true"`, your textbox is going to fire the `TextChanged` event as soon as the textbox loses focus - this includes trying to click on a button.

It might look like you're having to click the button twice, but what's actually happening is: -

1. you go to click on a button or set the focus to another control
2. the  default ASP.NET client-side javascript posts the form, and your
   textbox's TextChanged event fires
3. the page loads again
4. you can now press the Save button (or move the focus to another control) without causing the TextChanged event again

You can verify this by attaching a debugger and putting a breakpoint inside your TextChanged event.

Comment: thanks! Any workaround so the perception isn't a double click?

Comment: If you can avoid it, don't put code in TextChanged - collect up the contents of the GridView and save it as a single batch, triggered from your Save button click

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately the workflow doesn't allow for that. There are 2 grids. The bottom grid has all available items to "add". The top grid contains what they've added and they are allowed to adjust some values. So, I click add in the bottom grid, then they fill in some values in the top grid, but at any time they can click an add button again in the bottom grid without saving first. I don't want to lose any values they've customized. Hope this makes sense. @sh1rts

Comment: I'd suggest using jQuery AJAX to post text changed events in your grid to an HttpHandler if you have to have immediate saving of the top grid (the one containing the products and quantities for the order)